# How do I in some way save a texture (with borders, effects and all) in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects, illustrator-effects

I have multiple objects that will have the same color, border color, brush and texture (with texturizer). How can I either save this as some default style, or copy everything from one object to another? The eye dropper will only copy the colors and not the texture and brush...

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to use the `Graphic Styles` panel in Illustrator.

---

The first step is to create a template object that has the color, border color, brush and texture that you want all of the objects to have.
[image: Template Object]
Next, drag that object into your `Graphic Styles` panel.
[image: Create Style]
Then, select the target objects you wish to look like your template object.
[image: Target Objects]
And lastly, with those target objects selected, just click the style you created from the `Graphic Styles` panel.
[image]