# How can I do this kind of color effect in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, sketch-app, pencil

I was trying to get this color effect done using adobe illustrator but could not do it. How can I do that?

[image: Hand color effect]

Comment: This *could* be done in Illustrator but  probably better done in a raster program (like Photoshop). The coloring in Illustrator would be easy, but the shading and textures would require a lot of pretty complex work. What have you tried ? Where did you run into trouble ?

Comment: Actually, I need it in the .ai file. That is why I could not find any source to come to this result. :(

Comment: This looks like it was done by hand using crayons. Not easily achievable digitally. You could use some colorized raster textures or noise, but in your example the texture partly follows the shapes of the figure. If I only had to do one or a few, I would print out the outline, color by hand and scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been an Illustrator user for more than 30 years and I would not attempt this type of multi-colored texture in Illustrator.

If you look at the face, for example, there's not only texture there, but several colors and hue shifts *within* the texture. All that happens naturally with crayons on paper. Mimicking it digitally is challenging. Mimicking it digitally with *vectors* may be more a lesson in frustration than anything else.

Ultimately, in Illustrator, this would require **many** textures. If such textures are vector in nature, it can cause exceptional lags the more you create. Or... to prevent technical issues with the app, the use of raster effects or raster images for textures/opacity masks. Because the optimum method of adding the textures would require raster, I don't see a great deal of point in using AI for anything beyond the key line.

In addition, the subtle hue variations *within* the textures are near impossible in AI.

Note that you *can* add some textures in AI.

- [Clipping mask is filling the wrong part of the shape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/138881/clipping-mask-is-filling-the-wrong-part-of-the-shape)
- [How do I create a similar texture in illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83563/how-do-i-create-a-similar-texture-in-illustrator)
- [How do I in some way save a texture (with borders, effects and all) in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31826/how-do-i-in-some-way-save-a-texture-with-borders-effects-and-all-in-illustrat)
- [How can I achieve this type of texture in illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132362/how-can-i-achieve-this-type-of-texture-in-illustrator)

It is simply that AI is not geared to supporting overly textured coloring. Again multi-colored textures, as in the sample, are pretty impossible unless one were to overlay textures on textures on textures.

---

I'd hazard a guess, *most* trying to mimic the texture of the sample image would jump to a raster editor where it is lightyears easier.

This is akin to trying to build a full 3D scene in AI with proper shading, light, perspective, foreshortening, etc. ... sure you *can* with enough effort, but why spend 2 years on something when using the proper application means you get it done in 2 days, if not 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are referring to shading aspects it can be done with some gradient mesh (hotkey U). In order to get this pencil colouring style you will certainly need to use some brush sets (and a lot of patience). Try getting some kyle brushes on adobe official website. It will probably do the trick.
Otherwise, you can try applying some illustrator native artistic filters and effects but I`m almost sure it wont come to the desired result.

Comment: If I am not wrong kyle brushes are for photoshop, right?
I need to do this in vector format that is why I am struggling! With photoshop it can be done easily.

Comment: My bad! Kyle`s are exclusive for PS but there are plenty of vector brushes from websites like Envato, Brusheezy, ProBrush and other. If i may give you a tip: Never, NEVER! outline your vector brushe strokes. It will certainly create a plethora of shapes that may crash your aplication